# taking average of 10 sample in vb2010

Tags: vb.net

I have used below code to find average of 10 sample . But during first time it take sample and do the averaging . during next cycle counter not become Zero.and text box not updating

```
Static counter As Integer = 0
DIm average_sum As Double = 0

If counter < 10 Then
    counter = counter + 1
    Count_val.Text = counter
    Dim array(10) As Double
    For value As Integer = 0 To counter
         array(counter) = k
         average_sum = average_sum + array(counter)
    Next
    If counter = 10 Then
        average_sum = average_sum / array.Count
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250)
        Array_count.Text = average_sum

    End If
    If counter > 10 Then
        average_sum = 0
        counter = 0

    End If


End If
```

Comment: what is the value of `k` here? what are you trying to figure out? do you want to find the sum and avg of numbers up to ten?

Comment: K is taking from serial arduio. So since code became very long to post . Data collecting properly from arduino

Comment: @NeethuSoman yes i want to take 10 sample reading sum it  and when count is 10 take average

Comment: `counter > 10` will always be false because the outer `If` ensures than the maximum value of `counter` will be 9 when entering the block and you only add 1 to it.

Comment: @AndrewMorton for saeme above code . I found Avg_count  is not incrementin properly.

Comment: Please put `Option Strict On` at the top of your code or set it in your projects properties under `Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > VB Defaults`.   This will help you to write better code.

Answer (score 1):

```
   If Avg_count < 10 Then
                Dim array(10) As Double
                For value As Double = 0 To Avg_count
                    array(Avg_count) = k
                    average_sum = average_sum + array(Avg_count)
                    Avg_count = Avg_count + 1
                Next

                If Avg_count = 10 Then
                    average_sum = average_sum / Avg_count
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250)
                    Average.Text = average_sum
                    Avg_count = 0
                End If

            End If
```

Here count value setting properly . But after 2 to3 cycle Average will done earlier itself same thing i writen in excel to compare averages but not matching with average and excel sheet data

Below is excel sheet code.Both code are in timer1 block.

```
If counter < 10 Then
                'counter = 0
                'average_sum = 0


                Dim headerText = ""
                Dim csvFile As String = IO.Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "Current.csv")
                If Not IO.File.Exists((csvFile)) Then
                    headerText = "Date,TIME ,Current, "

                End If

                Using outFile = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(csvFile, True)
                    If headerText.Length > 0 Then
                        outFile.WriteLine(headerText)
                    End If
Dim date1 As String = "25-10-2014"
                    Dim time1 As String = TimeOfDay()
                    Dim x As String = date1 + "," + time1 + "," + distance
                    outFile.Write(x)

                End Using
            End If
            If counter > 10 Then
                counter = 0
            End If
```

Comment: But here i assigned constant count. If use Avg_count is not increment properly